# Check if string exists in a text file

Tags: python, regex

So I've got:

```
def CheckUserExists(user):
    with open("C:/~/database.txt", 'r') as file:
        if re.search(user, file.read()):
            return True
        else:
            return False

username = input("Please enter you Username: ")
if CheckUserExists(username) == True:
    print("You exist!")
else:
    print("This user does not exist...")
```

However if you enter for example the letter 'a' and the is a user called 'brain'; the search picks up the a and returns True. How do I search for whole words?

I have looked here: [How to check in Python if string is in a text file and print the line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432203/python-checking-if-string-is-in-a-text-file) however I don't understand the piece of code:

```
re.search("\b{0}\b".format(w),line)
```

Comment: `\b` is used for word boundary.

Comment: RE seems like overkill, why not just see `if user in file.read()`. Or read the file line by line.

Comment: What's the format of this file?

Comment: The file is a text file; and     if user in file.read()     still returns True for letters in a word

Comment: plus one, interesting question

Comment: what is the format of the input file? Are there more than one user per line in the file? How user names are separated from each other in `database.txt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular expression, `\b`, [refers to the empty string at a word boundary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), where word is `\w+`, or `[A-Za-z0-9_]+`

If you have one name per line (with no other whitespace around the names), you can search by line with `^{0}$` with the `re.M` or `re.MULTILINE` flag

That would look like this:

```
def CheckUserExists(user):
    with open("C:/~/database.txt", 'r') as file:
        if re.search('^{0}$'.format(re.escape(user)), file.read(), flags=re.M):
            return True
        else:
            return False

username = input("Please enter you Username: ")
if CheckUserExists(username): # it's redundant to check if == True here
    print("You exist!")
else:
    print("This user does not exist...")
```

Although a comment and an answer suggest, if you do

```
if user in file.read()
```

you may have false positives.

Comment: use `return bool(x)` instead of `if x: return True else: return False`. Use `if x:` instead of `if x == True:`

Comment: you want `'^{}$'.format(re.escape(user))` if `user` might contain regex metacharacters.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian can you give me an example of such a name? Nah, that's probably a good idea, defeat malicious purposes I suppose. :D

Comment: example: `J.F.Sebastian` (`.` has special meaning inside a regex). Unless it is your intent to allow to search users using a regex pattern; you should escape the input.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I'd rather do a validation, but at this point it goes beyond scope of the question I think.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian you're right, that's the question, not semantically a user, but a generic string, edited.

Answer (score 2):

To check whether a space-separated word exists in a file:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    found = (word in file.read().split())
```

Or the same but reading line by line instead of loading all in memory:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    found = any(word in line.split() for line in file)
```

If the format of the file is one word (/user) per line:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    found = any(word == line.strip() for line in file)
```

You don't need regular expressions in simple cases. If there could be multiple words per line and there could be arbitrary punctuation within then you could use the regex that you've linked:

```
import re

matched = re.compile(r"\b" + re.escape(word) + r"\b").search
with open(filename) as file:
    found = any(matched(line) for line in file)
```

`\b` regular expression matches a word boundary (start or the end of a word). Word characters are letters, digits, and underscore. `re.escape()` is used in case `word` contains regex metacharacters such as `*`.

Comment: Using `return (word in file.read().split())` directly would shorten OP's function even more, and still work.

Answer (score 0):

The line of code you reference is a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).  Basically what it does in this case is ensure that a word boundary (designated with `\b`) exists around the string you are searching for, which will prevent substring matches like the one you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Regex seems a little overly complicated for the task... I'll use `.split()` to divide each line in the file

```
def CheckUserExists(user):
  with open("C:/~/database.txt", 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
      if user in line.split():
        return True
    else:
      return False
```

This for a database.txt file made '''like''' a database with spaces between users.
We need a little extract of the source data to give you a consistent answer.

If users are delimited by special characters (quotes, periods, commas, etc..) I'll use `.replace("delimitingcharacter", " ")`..

```
def CheckUserExists(user):
  with open("C:/~/database.txt", 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
      for word in line.split():
        if user in word.replace(';', ' '):
          return True
        else:
          return False
```