# Check content of text file and add content if it's not there

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, string-comparison

I am new to python. I am designing a quotes app using python.  I am getting the quotes of the day from the brainy quote websites using BeautifulSoup. I would append it to the text file. In here, if the quotes of the day are already added, when I execute the program again, it should skip it. How to make it possible

Here's the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import socket
import requests
import subprocess
import datetime
def quotenotify():
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%b %d")
    res = requests.get('https://www.brainyquote.com/quote_of_the_day')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

    image_quote = soup.find('img', {'class': 'p-qotd bqPhotoDefault bqPhotoDefaultFw img-responsive delayedPhotoLoad'})
    quoteday=image_quote['alt']
    text_file = open("quotes.log", "a+")
    text_file.write("%s"%timestamp+"\t"+"%s"% quoteday)
    text_file.write("\n")
    text_file.close()
    return
quotenotify()
```

output in a file:

```
Mar 29  Where there is a great love, there are always wishes. - Willa Cather
Mar 29  Where there is great love, there are always wishes. - Willa Cather
```

Comment: Before you write to the file, open it in a read mode and check if the `quoteday` already exists in it

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try that way.

Comment: Look this up:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432203/how-to-check-in-python-if-string-is-in-a-text-file-and-print-the-line

Comment: Also, it is better for file handling using `with`

Comment: Also, why is there an empty `return`?

Comment: Also, these lines `image_quote = soup.find('img', {'class': 'p-qotd bqPhotoDefault bqPhotoDefaultFw img-responsive delayedPhotoLoad'})
    quoteday=image_quote['alt']` can be replaced with `image_quote = soup.find('img', {'class': 'p-qotd bqPhotoDefault bqPhotoDefaultFw img-responsive delayedPhotoLoad'})['alt']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from the comments:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import datetime

def quotenotify():
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%b %d")
    res = requests.get('https://www.brainyquote.com/quote_of_the_day')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    image_quote = soup.find('img', {'class': 'p-qotd bqPhotoDefault bqPhotoDefaultFw img-responsive delayedPhotoLoad'})['alt']
    with open("quotes.log", "w+") as f:
        if image_quote not in f.read():
            f.write("%s"%timestamp+"\t"+"%s"% image_quote + "\n")

quotenotify()
```

**EDIT**:

Since using the mode `w+` would truncate the file, I'd suggest going with pathlib:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import datetime
from pathlib import Path

def quotenotify():
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%b %d")
    res = requests.get('https://www.brainyquote.com/quote_of_the_day')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    image_quote = timestamp + "\t" + soup.find('img', {'class': 'p-qotd bqPhotoDefault bqPhotoDefaultFw img-responsive delayedPhotoLoad'})['alt']
    with open("quotes3.log", "a+") as f:
        contents = [Path("quotes3.log").read_text()]
        print(contents)
        print(image_quote)
        if image_quote not in contents:
            f.write("%s" % timestamp + "\t" + "%s" % image_quote + "\n")

quotenotify()
```

Comment: @SmackAlpha Use `w+` instead of `r+`

Comment: Changing the content in txt file and executed it again, it just replacing the content instead of adding it to the next line

Comment: @SmackAlpha Crap, I just remembered. it truncates the file. Give me a moment and i'll update with a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @DirtyBit, you should open the file in read mode first and load the content onto a variable.

You can see in my example below that I load the content onto a variable, then append to the file only if the variable is not inside the text file.

```
text_file = open('test-file.txt', 'r+')
read_the_file = text_file.read()
text_file.close()

text_file = open('test-file.txt', 'a+')
new_string = 'Smack Alpha learns python'

if new_string not in read_the_file:
    text_file.write(new_string + '\n')
text_file.close()
```